# Nginx ngx_http_access_module deny being trumped by redirect

Tags: nginx

When I put a `deny` in the `http` context, a `server -> location` context is still executing its redirect.

Given this very basic nginx.conf:

```
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  deny 127.0.0.1;

  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;

    root    /home/johndoe/html;
    index   index.html index.htm;

    location /redirect {
      return 301 /;
    }
  }
}
```

My expectation is all connections from 127.0.0.1 would be refused; this is true when a resource is requested:

```
$ curl -I 127.0.0.1
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

But not true if the redirect is invoked:

```
$ curl -I 127.0.0.1/redirect
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
```

Can someone explain why this is happening? How do I deny access to the `location` context in this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario the redirect is occurring because it is rewriting the header to 301. Rewrites precede everything in nginx flow because it is the first phase to be executed.

In your example the redirect will still occur, but after that the next connection will be refused.

Comment: It's wrong answer. The truth is that rewrite phase goes before access check. See http://wiki.nginx.org/Phases

Comment: Alexey, the link you posted does indeed show the "location rewrite" phase happening (and exiting the processing) before access. Feel free to write up an answer on that.